# Crashlytics uploading a ipa file does not upload DSYM file

Tags: ios, crashlytics, crashlytics-beta

I'm trying to upload a dSYM file to Crashlytics BETAS separately as we are currently in our build script only uploading the ipa file using Crashlytics.framework/submit. 
To upload a dlsym I'm trying to use Crashlytics.framework/uploadDSYM. It is constantly failing and giving me the following error.

```
warning: using uploadDSYM directly to upload dSYMs is not supported.     
uploadDSYM will be deprecated in a future release
Crashlytics: Failed to Detect Build Environment

BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR value not found in environment
```

Since it won't work what can I use to upload my DSYM every time, without actually having to manually upload it every time.

I couldn't find any documentation on this function on how to use it and what parameters I have to use. Currently I am using the following code to try to upload my DSYM to crashlytics BETAS

```
Path/to/Crashltics.framework/uploadDSYM $API_KEY $BUILD_SECRET -p ios /Path/to/DSYM
```

Comment: dsym file upload automatically when you upload app from xcode, some time dsym not upload from xcode so need to upload manualy. or in case of crashlytics may have expire your dsym can you check? how to check dsym expired or not??

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. The submit script for uploading versions to Beta is distinct from any upload process for dSYMs. Using the [upload-symbols](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#upload-symbols-script) script is a good way to automate dSYM uploads:

```
/Applications/Fabric.app/Contents/MacOS/upload-symbols -a <api-key> -p ios /Users/YourUserName/PathToDsymLocation
```

Comment: This used to work before Xcode 10 / iOS 12, what has changed? We did not have to call a separate script to upload symbols, the build phase script from your guide [here](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install) was enough to get crashes, do we now have to add one more script to get the the stack traces?

Comment: Xcode 10 changed the build process so that dSYM creation is less determent then  it was previously. Using the upload symbols script is a more descriptive way to know what's going on.

Comment: What's the main objective of the build phase script from the guide provided then? It also highly confusing for me that it now requires access to the Info.plist as an input file (in order to read the API key I guess?) if the API key is also passed as a parameter to the command.

Comment: It looks like what I was mentioning (dsym upload used to work before Xcode 10) was a issue from Crashlytics and was fixed in 3.10.8
"Fixed a bug preventing Xcode 10 users from uploading dSYMs in some cases." as seen [here](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/update)